# not able to install gcc correctly on linux

Tags: linux, gcc, installation

when i enter follwing command:

```
yum install gcc
```

this gives me that latest version of gcc compiler installed on your system, but when i am going to run simple c file as following, it gives me the error as following

```
[root@localhost ~]# gcc abc.c
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:385,
             from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
             from abc.c:1:
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:9:27: error: gnu/stubs-64.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What Linux distro is that? Clearly one of the RPM-based ones, but that's still lots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing these:

```
yum install glibc glibc-devel gcc-c++
```

Answer (score 2):

In Fedora 23+:

```bash
sudo dnf install glibc-devel.x86_64
```